# JQuery Cannot compare current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I'm going to compare 2 date script, and get wrong result, Here are my code:

```
var current = new Date();
var date = new Date($(this).val());
alert(current) == "Sat Aug 23 2014 14:42:00 GMT+0700 (ICT)"
alert(date) == "Sat Aug 23 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (ICT)"
```

It means that the time is different. So how to clear time using Jquery?

Any solution will be appreciated.

- Note that `$(this).val() = "08/23/2014"`

Comment: from where `$(this).val()` is coming?

Comment: you want the diff. in days ?

Comment: Why are you comparing the alert?

Comment: Sorry I miss that, the value is that "08/23/2014"

Comment: Are you only comparing the day? or exact time too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how to clear time using Jquery?

You don't. jQuery doesn't have date/time functions. But you can with JavaScript:

```
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

That sets the time to midnight (local time), without affecting the date. (Even though it's called `setHours`, it has optional arguments for minutes, seconds, and milliseconds.)

If you want to set it to midnight UTC instead, use `setUTCHours`.

But if your goal is to compare `current` and `date` ignoring the time, you can do that with `toISOString` (on ES5 browsers; it can be shimmed on older ones):

```
if (date.toISOString().substring(0, 10) === current.toISOString().substring(0, 10)) {
    // They're the same
}
```

Or if you need to support older engines that don't have `toISOString` and you don't want to shim it, just do it field-by-field (probably in a reusable function)

```
// Returns 0 if they're equal, < 0 if a is less than b, and > 0 if a is greater than b
function compareDateOnly(a, b) {
    var rv;
    rv = a.getFullYear() - b.getFullYear();
    if (rv === 0) {
        rv = a.getMonth() - b.getMonth();
        if (rv === 0) {
            rv = a.getDate() - b.getDate();
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, really helpful. I'm using Groovy and easy to use getTime(). Anyway, thanks again.